# Can a shared component use its own private @ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ng-packagr

I am developing an Angular shared component (in its own repo, using ng-packagr and angular 5, to be published as an npm package) and I would like to use @ngrx/store because the component is complex enough to justify this. I would like the store to be internal to the component. In particular, this would mean that:

- integrating apps would not need to know about @ngrx to use my component
- integrating apps could use a separate @ngrx store from my component.

What kind of dependency relationships (in my component's `package.json`, such as peerDependencies or dependencies) and initialization code (in my component's main module `my-component.module.ts`) would my component need to accomplish this?

What kind of dependency relationships (in the integrating application's `package.json`) and initialization code (in the integrating application's main module `app.module.ts`) would the integrating application need to bring in, initialize, and use the component *once it is published*?

Comment: A BehaviorSubject could save a small state for a component, why would you use ngrx/store for a component state ? Is it that big ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the option that would be best in this case is the new [@ngrx/component-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store) package. I have used this in a project at work and highly recommend it for anything where you would otherwise use a slew of BehaviorSubjects to maintain the state within a component or its children